# How to position div which contains font-awesome icons to centre of another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to position div which contains font-awesome icons to centre of another div but i cannot make it in the right way.

I have following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menuRightSide" >
            <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
                <div class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="redirectToGamePage();" id="repeatIcon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
                <div class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="redirectToGamePage();" id="repeatIcon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
                <div class="fa fa-question fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="redirectToGamePage();" id="repeatIcon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menuRightSide {
position: absolute;
top: 36%;
right: 2%;
width: auto;
```

}

```
.rightSideMenuItem {
    background: url("../img/objects/side_menu_item.png") no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 1990;
    background-size: 100%;
    left: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 33%;
    /* padding-right: 20%; */
    /* margin-left: 20%; */
    position: relative;
}

.rightSideMenuItemIcon {
    color: #fff;

}
```

**Which produces something like that:**

[image]

But i would like to have to get result where icons are centered in the centre of the rightSideMenuItem div class with same padding on all sides to get result like this.

[image]

I tried to do it by way mentioned above but without luck. How can i do it in the right way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
body{background-color:black}

#menuRightSideGame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    right: 2%;
}
.rightSideMenuItem {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background: #c3834c;
    z-index: 1990;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px white;
    margin:20px;
    text-align: center; /* vor horizontal align */
}
.rightSideMenuItemIcon {
    color: #fff;
    line-height:70px; /* for vertical align, needs to be same as parent height */
}
```

```html
<div id="menuRightSide">
    <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
        <div class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="redirectToGamePage();" id="repeatIcon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
        <div class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="redirectToGamePage();" id="repeatIcon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
        <div class="fa fa-question fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="redirectToGamePage();" id="repeatIcon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Font awesome icons are basically texts, so this might help:

```
.rightSideMenuItem {
    background: url("../img/objects/side_menu_item.png") no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 1990;
    background-size: 100%;
    left: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 33%;
    /* padding-right: 20%; */
    /* margin-left: 20%; */
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/oq6adjwa/1/)**